# Firebase database - force read value on demand

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having problems to force read value from Firebase Realtime database. My application flow:

SplashActivity->LoginActivity->MainActivity. When user is logged, SplashActivity and LoginActivity don't exist. When user logs out, main activity is finished and LoginActivity is created again.

In MainActivity `onCreate` event, to retrieve interesting data from Firebase:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("appVariant");

    myRef.child("stable").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            AppVariant v = dataSnapshot.getValue(AppVariant.class);
            Log.d(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, String.format("Data change:  %s", v.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

It works fine, but only first time when `MainActivity` is created. If I logout (so MainActivity is finished), then login again (MainActivity recreated), `onDataChanged` never fires again.

How to force to get child value again, without restarting application? I need to retrieve data on demand, every time after user log in, one time (no any changes need to be monitored). Is that possible?

Comment: If you need to load the same data once every time a user logs in, you'll need to attach this same listener every time a user logs in.

Comment: Do you mean listener should not be recreated and it should exists beyond activity lifecycle?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what lifecycle methods fire for an Activity. `onCreate` only fires when the activity is initially created. If you want to load the data every time the activity is activated, put the code in `onStart()` or `onResume()`. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html for a good diagram

Comment: You are wrong. I have debugged it, I'm sure `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is called again, but not `onDataChange`. Note, that on logout, `MainActivity` finishes (by calling `fhinish` method) and it launches new LoginActiviwy instance. Then, after user login,`LoginActivity` launches new `MainActivity` instance, so `onCreate` will be fired again.

Comment: You're probably getting a "permission denied" in that case. Implement `onCancelled` to catch it, e.g. `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Well, I'll see, it's rather not possible I'm not logged to Firebase at this stage

Answer (score 1):

This is not the normal flow of the authentication process. If you have two different activities (let's omit the SplashActivity) like `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity`, you should consider doing the following operations:

1. Make your LoginActivity, as the default activity your appliation starts in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file
2. Add the MainActivity as another activity
3. Add the authentication logic inside LoginActivity.
4. Create an `authStateListener` in your LoginActivity to check the state of user authentication. If `firebaseUser != null` then redirect the user to the MainActivity.
5. Create an `authStateListener` also in your MainActivity to check the state of user authentication. If `firebaseUser == null` then redirect the user to the LoginActivity.

Once you are authenticated, you can use listeners without fearing that your activity will restart.

And that's it. For a better understanding, if you have time, take a look on one of my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5&t=3s) where I have explained step by step, all the authentication process using two different activities.

Comment: My flow is almost identical as yours. The only difference: I DO NEED to finish `LoginActivity` before launch `MainActivity`, because `MainActivity` needs to be at the top of stack after user login. Otherwise, on Back button click, LoginActivity will be shown, which is wrong. The same goes after logout: need to finish main activity and launch LoginActivity, otherwise, when user click Back button, previous instance of MainAcitivity will be shown.Authentication logic is inside LoginActivity. Can you be more specific what's wrong in my approach?

Comment: P.S. default activity is SplashActivity, it launchers LoginActivity, then LoginActity (after succesful login) launchers MainActivity.

Comment: As Frank mentioned, it's all about the lifecycle methods of an Activity. And it's always a good practice to implement `onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)` because it can provide you the exact error.

Comment: Sorry for no response from me and thanks for trying to help. Reason why there was no response from me is I was unable to check it so far (many projects, this one needs to be paused for a while because of priorities). I'm going to check everything again soon, then accept your answer or provide more info eventually.